# How to only show filters that are on the pivot table

Tags: vba, excel

I am having difficulties in trying to get only the pivot items that is shown in the pivot table to be added to the combo box. I tried using the visible property of the filters but it did not work. For example, my data is sorted by a Country and Cities. Cities will of course be subset of a particular country, but both of them are 2 different pivot fields. The pivot has been sorted previously by countries and only a few cities are left on the pivot table. But if I use the visible property on cities all pivot items will be visible. How can I restrict cities i add to my combo table.

```
For Each item In Sheets("Pivot").PivotTables(1).PivotFields("Cities").PivotItems
        If item.Visible Then
            Sheets("Dashboard").ComboBox1.AddItem item.Name
        End If
    Next item
End If
```

Please advise

Thank you!

Comment: not sure but have you tried this? `If item.Visible = True Then`

Comment: I tried but it seems like the same, therefore i just kept it as that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `.DataBodyRange` property. This will remove all headers and only get the data present in the ranges present. Since it only excludes the column header, do a check to exclude `Grand Total`.

Since `.DataBodyRange` is of the `Range` type, you can use `.Cells(x,y)` on it to target specific columns or rows (assuming you have more than one column showing in your Pivot Table). See my code and screenshots below.

Code below:

```
Sub GetVisibleCells()
    Sheets("Sheet4").ComboBox1.Clear
    For Each Item In Sheets("Sheet4").PivotTables(1).DataBodyRange
            If Item <> "Grand Total" Then
                Sheets("Sheet4").ComboBox1.AddItem Item
            End If
    Next Item
End Sub
```

**Data:**

[image]

**Pivot (Selected Category `B` To Filter Values):**

[image]

**Result:**

[image]

Of course, this is easy since I only have a one-column set-up so `.DataBodyRange` defaults to just that. Applying it on larger ranges/pivot tables, this I leave up to you. ;)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your ans! I think I am able to do it now. I used .RowRange to get all the filter names only though. Thanks :)

Comment: @AfterTheRain: You're welcome and thanks for accepting. VBA + pivot tables are just plain amazing. I have been saved many a time by combination of both (end of year reports!). Always check the object explorer when you're stuck. ;) Good luck!